# Discord.js - Get list of Users who reacted to a Message and assign them roles depending on their reaction

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, dom-events, javascript-objects

I have created a Discord bot which is working just fine. Except the code snippet shown below, which is responsible to add users to roles depending on their emoji reaction to the message of message ID, "870228060643946537", in the channel of channel ID, "870225876892131348".

The following are the Role IDs to be assigned corresponding to the Emoji name:

```
Red: "870162738561814578"
Blue: "870162842983206922"
Yellow: "870162885412810773"
```

But it assigns only those users who reacted during the bot being alive. I want the bot to add all those users to the suitable roles who reacted to that particular message even when the bot was not alive or was not in the Server.

I am expecting to somehow get the list of users who reacted to the message with these emojis and assing them the suitable roles. How do I do this?

Heres the code snippet:

```
const message = '870228060643946537';
const channel = '870225876892131348';
const RYellow = '870162885412810773';
const RBlue = '870162842983206922';
const RRed = '870162738561814578';
const RRedEmoji = 'Red';
const RBlueEmoji = 'Blue';
const RYellowEmoji = 'Yellow';

client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction) await reaction.fetch();
    if (user.bot) return;
    if (reaction.message.id == message) {
        if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
            if (reaction.emoji.name === RYellowEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(RYellow);
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(RRed);
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(RBlue);
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === RRedEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(RRed);
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(RYellow);
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(RBlue);
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === RBlueEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(RBlue);
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(RRed);
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(RYellow);
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
});

client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction) await reaction.fetch();
    if (user.bot) return;
    if (reaction.message.id == message) {
    if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === RYellowEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(RYellow);
            }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === RRedEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(RRed);
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === RBlueEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(RBlue);
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The bot must be running in order to take events.

Comment: On your bot's startup, you could fetch the specific message object by id and access [`Message.reactions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reactions) property. Which contains all the reactions, that were cast on the message, no matter the bot being online.

Comment: @KingFriday I understand what you mean, but it is not necessary to take events. What i want is, the bot should check the list of users who already reacted to that message.

Comment: You could simply fetch your message (and perform the necessary actions) with the `ready` event, which is what I think @SkulaurunMrusal meant by "On your bot's startup".